# Text too big while exporting to xls

Tags: php, export-to-excel

I'm using this classic *php* script to export data from a *mysql database* to an *.xls* file:

```
function xlsBOF() {
        echo pack("ssssss", 0x809, 0x8, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0);
        }
        function xlsEOF() {
            echo pack("ss", 0x0A, 0x00);
        }
        function xlsWriteNumber($Row, $Col, $Value) {
            echo pack("sssss", 0x203, 14, $Row, $Col, 0x0);
            echo pack("d", $Value);
        }
        function xlsWriteLabel($Row, $Col, $Value) {
            $L = strlen($Value);
            echo pack("ssssss", 0x204, 8 + $L, $Row, $Col, 0x0, $L);
            echo $Value;
        } 
        // prepare headers information
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Type: application/download");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"export_".date("Y-m-d").".xls\"");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Expires: 0");
        // start exporting

        xlsBOF();
```

The problem takes place when, for `xlsWriteLabel($r, $c, $value);` I use a value which is a medium length *string* - **not bigger than 500 characters**.

The value is not printed and I get the following error message:

**File error: data may have been lost.**

For smaller strings everything works ok.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The cell size limit for text in a BIFF-format xls file is 255 characters; unless the file uses extension buckets, when the limit is 1k characters

Comment: unless the file uses extension buckets -> how can I do that?

Comment: You can, but you'd need to rewrite your simple Writer to create extension records and split the text between the extensions..... which is a non-trivial task

Comment: @MarkBaker I want to learn, it seems interesting. Any tutorial as a starting point?

Comment: You're not going to find any easy tutorials for this..... the best is to read the BIFF format documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313154(v=office.12).aspx), but easier to switch to a decent PHP/Excel Writer library that should be capable of handling this

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you! I hope sometime soon I'll be able to write my own export class